# On Back app crashes not working in 6s, at MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the **`MBProgressHUD`** for showing the please wait dialog. I have created common method for showing and hiding the dialog.

Going from controller A to B and B to C, on back of Controller C , application get crashed.

In Controller B , I have written this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

if ([cF isConnected] == YES) {

    @try {
        [cS showProgressDialog:self.view labelText:PLEASE_WAIT];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [self onCategorySelectDataWebservice];

        });

       // [self onCategorySelectDataWebservice];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
    }


}else{
    [cF makeToast:NETWORK_ERROR];
}
self.navigationItem.title = collectionTitleFromLanding;

}
```

I have tested on 4s it is working on simulator it is working bur not working in 6s.

Following the method

```
- (void) showProgressDialog: (UIView *) view
                  labelText: (NSString *) labelText {
    @try{
        progressDialog = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo: view animated: YES];
        progressDialog.delegate = self;
        progressDialog.color =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        progressDialog.activityIndicatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0666 green:0.1411 blue:0.2823 alpha:1.0];

        progressDialog.labelText = labelText;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception e %@", exception);
    }
}
```

And for hiding using the

```
- (void) hideProgressDialog {
    [progressDialog hideAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you post crash report?

Comment: Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.Bundle [1949]
Date/Time:           2016-10-18 12:27:03.1052 +0530
Launch Time:         2016-10-18 12:26:48.4353 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: @Misha Crash report

Comment: do you mean when you go back to controller B?

Comment: yes going from c to b

Answer (score 0):

Run the MBProgressHUD on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    progressDialog = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo: view animated: YES]; 
     });
```

Comment: facing same issue